# How to plot 3D plots on top of each other and highlight their intersection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 dataframes that look like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 
                  'z':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'w':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 
                  'z':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'w':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})
```

From these two dataframes using this function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st

def plot_2d_kde(df):
    # Extract x and y
    x = df['x']
    y = df['y']
    # Define the borders
    deltaX = (max(x) - min(x))/10
    deltaY = (max(y) - min(y))/10
    xmin = min(x) - deltaX
    xmax = max(x) + deltaX
    ymin = min(y) - deltaY
    ymax = max(y) + deltaY

    # Create meshgrid
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]

    # We will fit a gaussian kernel using the scipy’s gaussian_kde method
    positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    values = np.vstack([x, y])
    kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
    f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 7))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='coolwarm', edgecolor='none')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('PDF')
    ax.set_title('Surface plot of Gaussian 2D KDE')
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5) # add color bar indicating the PDF
    ax.view_init(60, 35)
```

I can produce these two plots

```
plot_2d_kde(A)
```

[image]
plot_2d_kde(B)
[image]
Is there a way to plot these two plots together and highlight their intersection ? By intersection I mean the surface which is common for both plots

Comment: I think "intersection" should be defined more rigorously. No two 3d points will be exactly overlapping, which can yield an infinity of possible solutions. Please define better what exactly is the intersection you are looking for.

Comment: By intersection I mean the surface which is common for both plots. So they do not need to completely overlap, but they will partially overlap. I added it to the question as well. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Again, plots are really point clouds. There isn't really any "surface" per-se. Can you add images of your plots please?

Comment: Updated with the kde plots :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by word "surface" but from my intuition intersection will be a 1d object, not 2d. So a curve rather than a surface. Because these two plots are 2d surfaces

Comment: No time right now for implementing testing and answering, but here's what I'd do:
calculate the diff `np.abs(f1(x, y)-f2(x, y))` and then `(x3, y3) = np.where(diff<thres)` will be the x,y of your intersection.